# Powershell 4.0 - plink and table-like data

Tags: sql, unix, powershell, plink

I am running PS 4.0 and the following command in interaction with a Veritas Netbackup master server on a Unix host via plink:

```
PS C:\batch> $testtest = c:\batch\plink blah@blersniggity -pw "blurble" "/usr/openv/netbackup/bin/admincmd/nbpemreq -due -date 01/17/2014" | Format-Table -property Status
```

As you can see, I attempted a "Format-Table" call at the end of this.

The resulting value of the variable ($testtest) is a string that is laid out exactly like the table in the Unix console, with Status, Job Code, Servername, Policy... all that listed in order. But, it populates the variable in Powershell as just that: a vanilla string.

I want to use this in conjunction with a stored procedure on a SQL box, which would be TONS easier if I could format it into a table. How do I use Powershell to tabulate it exactly how it is extracted from the Unix prompt via Plink?

Comment: What does the output of plink look like without the Format-Table or variable assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to parse it and create PS Objects to be able to use the format-* cmdlets.  I do enough of it that I wrote this to help:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/New-PSObjectFromMatches-87d8ce87

You'll need to be able to isolate the data and write a regex to capture the bits you want.

Comment: PowerShell team member Lee Holmes also wrote a script for this called Parse-TextObject http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2005/11/14/parse-textobject-%e2%80%93-awk-with-a-vengeance/

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't seen that.  It's looks like it's doing pretty much the same thing, but using split elements intead of capture groups to separate the data fields.

Comment: I'll second that, I used `New-PSObjectfrommatches` for the first time on Monday to parse `net view` command results and it's awesome :-)

Comment: Thank you all for the comments! I'll test these out and mark the answer in a bit.